# W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType disconnect failed

Tags: android, warnings, logcat

I am seeing tons of warnings in my Android logcats of the form

```
 W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x72543469d0 disconnect failed
```

without further explanation. Why is this? Did not find anything useful on Google. Android 11 device. Unfortunately, I can not give more details.

```
  10:42:46.662 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: release : mNativeObject = 486206861488 - Surface(name=Surface(name=be52245 StatusBar)/@0x1380023 - animation-leash)/@0x9c54a2e
  10:42:46.662 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[486206861488]
  10:42:46.662 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[486206861488]
  10:42:46.716 5720-6276/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x72543469d0 disconnect failed
  10:42:46.725 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: release : mNativeObject = 486206642976 - Surface(name=null)/@0x32ec9cf
  10:42:46.725 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject s[486206642976]
  10:42:46.725 5720-5720/com.floritfoto.apps.xvf I/SurfaceControl: nativeRelease nativeObject e[486206642976]
```

Comment: were you able to figure out what caused this ?

Comment: No... I have several messages like this in Android Studio that have no idea about the cause.